# Restart-Computer does not have a -UseSSL parameter, gets stuck on "Waiting for WinRM"

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell v3.0. Like the title suggests, I cannot effectively use `Restart-Computer -ComputerName *RemoteComputer* -Wait` because the command gets stuck trying to connect to WinRM.

I need SSL to communicate to all my hosts, so I use -UseSSL when calling Invoke-Command or Enter-PSSession. Without that, the command fails and I'm guessing it's for the same reasons that the WinRM check fails.

How do I properly restart a remote computer and wait for the restart to complete in my scenario?

Comment: If DCOM is an option, you could use `-For DCOM -DcomAuthentication PacketPrivacy`. Alternative is to avoid `-Wait` and have the next statement attempt to establish a WSMan session in a while loop (ie. "manual waiting")

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen There is no DCOM option for the -For parameter, so I put it in the -Protocol parameter instead. No change.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Invoke-Command` to run the `Restart-Computer` command on the remote computer.

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Restart-Computer} -ComputerName test
```

or

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {shutdown -r -t 0} -ComputerName test
```

Of course, you'll have to add your -UseSSL parameter which I do not show because I do not know the syntax for it.

Comment: I'm trying to wait until the restart is complete. This command exits immediately.